# how to make this initialisation of numpy array work?

Tags: python, numpy

here is the sample code

```
A1 = relu(Z1)
D1 = np.random.randn(A1.shape)
```

D1 cannot be initialized by above 
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message. What do you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "unpack" the items in parameters by using an asterisk (`*`) in front of `A1.shape`:

```
D1 = np.random.randn(*A1.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [633]: A=np.zeros((3,4))                                                                            
In [634]: np.random.randn(*A.shape)                                                                    
Out[634]: 
array([[ 0.42267339,  0.09075801,  0.16493545,  0.96534338],
       [ 0.1899203 ,  1.43543348,  1.22381454, -0.88792278],
       [ 1.10075586,  1.35832023,  0.11406843, -1.51401401]])
```

`randn` docs is recommending using `standard_normal` which takes a tuple argument:

```
In [635]: np.random.standard_normal(A.shape)                                                           
Out[635]: 
array([[ 0.16811322, -0.46261632, -1.19500492,  0.64124171],
       [-0.17198705,  1.52709934, -1.51043158,  0.46563776],
       [-0.59715752,  1.09271112, -1.37173267,  0.744021  ]])
```